# serial port on RPi

Tags: serial

In the Arduino IDE on my RPi on the top there is a header that says, File, Edit, Tools and help.

Following a Magpi article it said to go to tools then serial port and change that depending on what board you use. The only problem is that it's not there, when I click tools I scroll down and there **grayed out** it says, serial port.

Why is this grayed out? And why can I not change it? Also, what port should be used for an Uno?

Answer (score 2):

It's greyed out because it can't find any serial ports.

That could be because:

- There aren't any detected (not got the right kernel modules loaded)
- You don't have permission to access the serial ports (are you in the `dialout` group?)

Have you followed the Linux installation instructions? http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/All

Answer (score 0):

That would require RTFM :)

For the last many years (on various linux variants including rpi) a quick solution is:

```
sudo chmod ugo+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

after plugging in the arduino.